# Default subdomain on ISPConfig 3

Tags: apache-2.2

In my ISPConfig installation I have installed Horde with IMP. This is my default webmail browser for my customers... but what I want is that whenever I add a domainname, the address `webmail.DOMAIN` will automaticly load the horde webmail.
Either by forwarding the user from `webmail.CLIENTDOMAIN` to `webmail.MYSERVERMAINDOMAIN.com`, or just by aliasing it.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no 'automatic' way to do this; having a subdomain requires a DNS record, and there's no concept of wildcarding there. For each client domain, you'll need to add a DNS CNAME alias from webmail.CLIENTDOMAIN.com to webmail.YOURSERVERDOMAIN.com; this is not an especially arduous thing to have to do, since you're already setting up a new domain anyway.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer... unfortunately someone can forget to create those records. What you described is what I did so far.. but I will have to write a plug-in for ispconfig to get it to work as I want. A plug-in that creates this automatically. Thanks for you answer.